# How to scheduled a nested timer

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsarray, nstimer

Right now, I have a array of `NSDate` like "00:00.00", "00:05.00", "00:15.00" etc. I have calc the `NSTimerInterval` so I can `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval`. But How to scheduled a nested timer when like 5 seconds later scheduled another 15 secs timer to do something and after that and so on until then end of array of dates. Each `NSTimerInterval` is calc from the `NSArray` of 2 objectes. I can get the first going like this:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"mm:ss.SS"];

NSDate *first = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[durationArray[0]]];
NSDate *second = [dateFormatter dateFromString:durationArray[1]];
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [second timeIntervalSinceDate:first];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timeInterval target:self selector:@selector(goToNextLine) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

if I do a for loop, the timer won't just fire after one after another:

```
for (int i = 0; i<[durationArray count]; i++) {
    int j = i+1;
    if (j == [durationArray count]) {

    } else
    {
        NSDate *first = [dateFormatter dateFromString:durationArray[i]];
        NSDate *second = [dateFormatter dateFromString:durationArray[j]];
        NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [second timeIntervalSinceDate:first];
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timeInterval target:self selector:@selector(goToNextLine) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    }
}
```

Comment: I would make use of the userInfo portion of the timer. You can use it to store the next timer's offset, and schedule the new timer when the previous one fires.  If the value is 0 then you simply stop making new timers :D.

Comment: P.S. Those are not NSDate objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timeInterval target:self selector:@selector(goToNextLine) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

hope this will help you `goToNextLine` method will execute with the time interval.